# How to mount removable storage with custom options?

Tags: mount, kubuntu

How can I change mount options for removable devices mounted by KDE's device manager?

Answer (score 2):

Running Kubuntu saucy, adding an entry to /etc/fstab works for me.  According to the udisks2 docs, fstab is respected as long as no mount options violate system security policies.  The docs also mention triggering a user authorization request in cases that do break security policy, however, I didn't need to worry about it in my case so I don't cover it here.

First, gather the info you'll need about your filesystem of choice.  Mount it using the device manager. Open a shell terminal window and:

```
$ mount
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda1 on /windows type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/user/16G-USB type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)
```

You will see many more devices than just the ones I have here.  The one you are looking for will likely be mounted under /media.  You can verify its mount point by finding it in a file manager.

Next, it's a good idea to get the UUID of the partition to identify it in /etc/fstab.  There is no guarantee that the device file, /dev/sdb1 in my case, will name your device. For example, if you use more than one removable drive, device files are given out in order of attaching them.  Using the device's LABEL is also not wise since it will likely be the same for any device of a given manufacturer's model of a given size.

```
$ ls -l /dev/disks/by-uuid
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 27 03:02 345A-B2EE -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Mar 25 11:35 5E0C-165B -> ../../mmcblk0p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 25 11:36 60cdd746-3be0-4d48-a03f-45ba7381db4f -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Mar 25 11:36 7913b72d-ab44-477e-9751-05f69baebfd6 -> ../../zram0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 25 11:36 A6305C91305C69F7 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Mar 25 11:36 c5323b04-6d7b-42d9-89ff-d1eddd2c008e -> ../../zram1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 25 11:36 d1980c70-8ee4-4f44-a4d3-fa1e12b2b123 -> ../../sda6
```

Look for the UUID which points to the device name you chose from the 'mount' command, above.  In my case, the device is /dev/sdb1 so the UUID is 345A-B2EE.

Now edit your /etc/fstab as root.  **Do this with care.  Mistakes can leave your system unbootable!** Back up your current /etc/fstab!

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
```

To edit with the 'pico' editor, for example:

sudo pico /etc/fstab

Using the UUID as the filesystem identifier, an fstab entry has the following format:

```
UUID=<filesystem uuid>  <directory to mount on> <filesystem type> <mount options> 0 0
```

can be either 'auto' or, more appropriately, the type listed in the output of the 'mount' command corresponding to your filesystem.

is the comma separated list of options for mounting the filesystem.

Don't use white-space (spaces, tabs, etc.) anywhere but field separators.  If you need to represent a space, for instance when mounting on a directory with a space in its name, replace the space with '\040'.

The 0 0 at the end of the line is beyond the scope of this howto.  Just don't forget them!

If you wish to add a comment for your entry, comment lines start with '#'.

It is probably wise to copy the mount options from the 'mount' command output, above, and only change what's needed.  You will want to add the option 'noauto' so your system doesn't try to mount a possibly non-existent device, at boot.  I also removed the 'uhelper=udisks2' option since, AFAIK, only udisks2 should be passing that option at mount time.

In my case, I wanted my drive to be told to clear blocks of deleted files at the time of deletion.  Certain flash drives are able to erase or 'trim' freed blocks, a slow process.  Doing this when deleting data means later writes, to the empty blocks, are significantly faster.  The mount option for this is 'discard'.  It only works with certain filesystems.  'vfat' happens to be one.

So, here is my final /etc/fstab entry:

```
#16G Kingston flash drive
UUID=345A-B2EE /media/user/16G-USB vfat rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,discard,noauto 0 0
```

You can do a basic syntax check of your new /etc/fstab by trying to mount something that doesn't exist, as root:

```
$ sudo mount /faketestfs
[mntent]: line 23 in /etc/fstab is bad
mount: can't find /fakefs in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

For an example error, I have a line in my fstab with nothing more than 'mntent'.  This test will only tell you that you have a file which MIGHT let you boot OK.  It won't necessarily catch errors in any options you have added for your new entry or certain errors which might prevent booting.

You may also want to use the 'diff' command to ensure the only changes you have made are those you intended:

```
$ diff /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak 
17,22c17
< #
< #16G Kingston USB Flash Drive
< UUID=345A-B2EE /media/user/16G-USB     vfat    rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,discard,noauto       0   0
---
>
```

Output showing any entry, other than your new addition, may mean your system won't boot.

If you aren't satisfied with either test, revert your changes:

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab.bak /etc/fstab
```

and start over.

P.S.  This may be long winded, but I thought I'd write for various levels of experience.

Cheers,
Jon